# Decay of Fourier coefficients of a smooth family of functions

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose $f(\theta, r)$ is defined on $\mathbb{T}^n \times \overline{B_R(0)}$, is smooth and has Fourier expansion $\displaystyle \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \widehat{f}_k(r)e^{ik.\theta}$. Is it true that for all positive integers $N$ there is a constant $C_N > 0$ so that for all $r \in B_R(0)$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{T}^n$, we would have $|\widehat{f}_k(r)| \le \dfrac{C_N}{|k|^N}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: I believe the answer is yes. It is definitely yes when $r$ is fixed. Check if the proof allows you  to take the sup over $r$.

Comment: Hi. Yes. It is correct in general as well. I understood why the next day. One can compute the Fourier coeffcients via their integral definitions. Now this formula is a smooth function of $r$ and will definitely obtain its maximum on the compact domain. To get the decay formula, one needs to apply this argument on any partial derivatives of order $N$.